Can't deploy solana contract on localnet
When i'm trying to deploy (anchor deploy) to localnet i get below:
``` Deploying cluster: http://127.0.0.1:8899
    Upgrade authority: /Users/bla/.config/solana/id.json
    Deploying program "gc_anchor_test"...
    Program path: /Users/bla/Desktop/git/solana/gc-anchor-test/target/deploy/gc_anchor_test.so...
    Error: Program's authority Some(11111111111111111111111111111111) does not match authority provided FjF6kYanAwqQYJcCacDdgRbmNT2EVExJ2tkP7NoUSmNd
    There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.

I already deployed it on devnet and everything goes well. 
Any advice?


Note that it looks like your program is already deployed on your test validator with a different authority.

It's quite common to get wrong program Ids in your compiled code (target folder). A typical solution is to delete the folder and recreate the build with anchor build.
If it doesn't work, try to create a new program id and sync it with your declare_id. Useful commands are: anchor keys list & anchor keys sync
